# JPAs deleteAll leaves one entry left in the table. How can I clearly delete all entries?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wrote some tests and found some crazy behavior.

```
      @Test
      public void clearTableOperation() {
       service.deleteAll();
       long existingEntriesAfterClear = service.count();

       assertTrue(existingEntriesAfterClear == ZERO, String.format("DB Table not 
       empty after clear all operation: %s", existingEntriesAfterClear));
       }
```

existingEntriesAfterClear is equal 1 not 0. Over 500 entries are deleted but this one left.

system print of last entry shows a real entry with id=0 value 1...value n to me.
Is it due to id=0 ? I have no other ideas.

```
MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>
```

My Service

```
  @CacheEvict(value = CachingConfiguration.CACHE_RESOLVER_NAME, allEntries = true)
  public void deleteAll() {
    repository.deleteAll();
  }
```

I use HSQLDB  and my Entity Class looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cars")
public class Cars extends AuditEntitySupport<String> {

  @Id
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", length = 10)
  private int id;

...some more colums, setter, getter, toString
```

For testing reasons I

- deleted the entry with id 0 from my sql import files -> everything works
- changed the id 0 to 806 of the entry that survive deleteAll() - > everything works
- replaced deleteAll() to repository.deleteAllInBatch(); -> works

Unfortunately, I do not understand the context

Comment: you are calling the `service`, what happens there before/after the call to the repository?

Comment: You have added no relevant code to your question.

Comment: Which database you are using? In your table are you using any sequence?

Comment: @AlanHay pls tell what exactly you need.

Comment: @SounakSaha I use HSQLDB an I use GenerationType.IDENTITY  if this is the question

Comment: @Tristate Enable log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG to get the actual query. It is very surprising 0 is not getting deleted.

Comment: @Tristate can you add your `service.count()` code?

Comment: @riorio this is just a repository count call